# Install utf8 collation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, locale, collation

Right now I can choose `Encoding : UTF8` when creating a new DB in pgAdmin4 GUI.

But, there is no option to choose `utf8_general_ci` as collation or character type. When I do `select * from pg_collation;` I dont see any collation relevant to `utf8_general_ci`.

Coming from a mySQL background I am confused. Do I have to install utf8-like ( eg `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_unicode_ci`) collation in my PostgreSQL 10 or windows10?

I just want to have the equivalent of `mySQL collation utf8_general_ci` to PostgreSQL.

Thank you

Comment: Note to readers: Postgres gained support for [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) collations in version 10 and later. See [post](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/icu-support-postgresql-10/) by Peter Eisentraut.

Answer (score 12):

`utf8` is an encoding (how to represent unicode characters as a series of bytes), not a collation (which character goes before which).

I think the Postgres 10 collation equivalent for `utf8_general_ci` (or more modern `utf8_unicode_ci`) is called `und-x-icu` - this is an undefined collation (not defined for any real world language) provided by an ICU library. This collation would sort quite reasonably characters from most languages.

ICU support is a [new feature added in PostgreSQL 10](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/icu-support-postgresql-10/), so this collation isn't available for older PostgreSQL versions or when it's disabled during compilation. Before that Postgres was using operating system provided collation support, which differs between operating systems.

Comment: Happy New Year. Yes I know the difference between encoding-collation. But thinking in mySQL terms, I meant any utf8-like collation (eg `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`). I edited my OP to be better written. Anyway, if `und-x-icu` is an undefined collation , then I could also use C collation, that is also an undefined collation , right? Thank you

Comment: I made some tests and it seems that in current version (10.1) ICU support is not as complete as I assumed. It seems that it's impossible to create a database with `und-x-icu` locale - only set it for some columns explicitly. So it seems that until it's improved you'd probably have to use `create database datname template='template0' encoding='UTF8' lc_ctype='C' lc_collate='C';` or other OS-provided locale.

Comment: Hi again. I have PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit in win10 laptop. I just did `CREATE DATABASE test
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    TEMPLATE = template0
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'und-x-icu'
    LC_CTYPE = 'und-x-icu'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;` and it worked. I can also see the properties in the pgAdmin4 GUI.

Comment: Also, I have to thank you because I didnt know about the ICU, you inform about it and it looks awesome , compared to C. It is not OS-depended, it is future proof, is based on Unicode standard for sorting and comparison (much like utf8_unicode_ci) , it implements the CLDR Collation Algorithm which is an extension of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) which is an extension of ISO 14651. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) , [here](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/) and [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation)

Comment: But, if you want, you can post a regular answer explaining the bugs you found.

Comment: Hello, testing on PG 11.1, Win10 x64 `CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH OWNER = postgres TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'und-x-icu' LC_CTYPE = 'und-x-icu' TABLESPACE = pg_default CONNECTION LIMIT = -1; COMMENT ON DATABASE dbname IS '...';` and it works.

Comment: `und-x-icu` seems to be supported only with 13+. I tried to use it and then `ILIKE` queries were case-*sensitive*. Using default collation made `ILIKE` search case-insensitive as expected.