# Get und-x-icu as collation and character type in Postgres 10 and win server 2008

Tags: postgresql, locale, windows-server-2008-r2, collation

I have successfully installed Postgres 10 in a Windows Server 2008 R2 standard, 64 bit.

I am trying to create a new database that has `LC_COLLATE = 'und-x-icu'` and  `LC_CTYPE = 'und-x-icu'` with the following SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE hey
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'und-x-icu'
    LC_CTYPE = 'und-x-icu'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    TEMPLATE = template0
    ;
```

I get `ERROR:  invalid locale name: "und-x-icu" SQL state: 42809`.

But the `SELECT *  FROM pg_collation;` clearly shows `und-x-icu`.

The same SQL works on my laptop (windows 10).

I did select `locale : C` while installing on the server, I did not remember what I selected as a locale while installing on the laptop.

How can I make this work on win server 2008 and get `und-x-icu`?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not seem to mention that restriction, but you cannot use ICU collations in `CREATE DATABASE`.

This may be improved in the future, but for now there is no way to have an ICU collation as the default collation.

Comment: On my laptop, I can set `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_CTYPE` as `'und-x-icu'` in the `CREATE DATABASE` , if I also set `TEMPLATE=template0`. But I can also see `'und-x-icu'` as a option in the Create > Database UI menu of pgAdmin4. Those options are not available in the win server 2008. So maybe its a win server OS thing? Should I check its available collations? Or somehow install ICU in server's Postgres ? But I think its already there. Thanks

Comment: That is scary. You definitely should get the same error message on your laptop. Something must be wrong there.

Comment: "scary" is a ...scary word. So, what could be wrong in my laptop setup? I dont remember doing anything special for enabling ICU. I just played around with `CREATE DATABASE` .If you see my comments in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044953/install-utf8-collation-in-postgresql) the SQL with `'und-x-icu'` just worked and the DB I am working on for months, works fine. Anyhow, what to chose instead of `und-x-icu` as collate and c type? Just C will be fine?

Comment: With "scary" I mean that this is maybe a PostgreSQL bug. What is the precise version of PostgreSQL on your laptop? If you create a new cluster with `initdb` on your laptop and try again to create a database with an ICU collation, does it work?

Comment: I am sorry ,but I dont know how or where to run the `initdb` . cmd? psql? I was experimenting without success. But I think its not a bug, since win 10 support ICU and in my `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin` I have the ICU .`dll` files. Win server has the same .`dll` files. Still nothing. I re-installed the whole Postgres on the server, chosing `locale : [Default locale]` this time and I still have C, POSIX and English 1252 as collate options

Comment: `initdb` is run in `cmd.exe`. If you never have created a cluster, you'd have to read some documentation first. I am not certain that it is a bug (I have no Windows machine at hand, so I cannot test), but to the best of my knowledge the error message is the correct behavior.