# Create database defnition equivalent from mysql to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I need to migrate a mysql table to postgresql.

I need an accent and case insensitive database.

In mysql, my database has the next definition:

```
CREATE DATABASE gestan 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

How do I create an equivalent definition to postgresql?

I have read some posts, but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 1):

```
create database getan
   encoding = 'UTF-8';
```

There is no direct equivalent for the case insensitive collation `_ci` in Postgres.

You can define a new [ICU collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html) that uses case insensitive comparison, but it can't be used as a default collation for a database, only for the collation on column level.

Related questions:

- [Install utf8 collation in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044953)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183355
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256979